# how to change to lower/upper in mysql workbench hotkey

Tags: mysql, keyboard, shortcut, workbench

I am wondering if there is a hotkey to change the code to lower or upper in MySQL workbench?

Like in MS SQL Server, you just press ctrl + shift + L/U and it changes your code to the either lower or upper case.

Thanks!!
EZ

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question... you can use: Edit -> Format -> UPCASE Keywords (but it has no shortcut key). This would change the Keywords in the selected texts to Uppercase: [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-main-menu.html)

There is no equivalent for SQL Server's ctrl + shift + L/U in MySQL Workbench.
MySQL Workbench recommends adopting a consistent convention, such as always creating and referring to databases and tables using lowercase names: [See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html)

### Update Dec 2020

Ctrl + Shift + U: now works and converts the text to UPPERCASE, but I could not figure out what is the shortcut for converting the text to lowercase... I think this is a bug, because MySQL workbench has not added the shortcut key to the menu either:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I did try that but it only changes the coding statements, such as select from,where, etc. However it does not change the text itself such as the table names or server names from the query.

Comment: yes i understand, the reason I asked was, because I was migrating a few tables manually from oracle SQL to MySQL, and for some reason those same tables names where named in caps on oracle, so when I exported them into .sql file all names were in caps. Any way, what I did was open those .sql files with notepad++ and use lowercase option there =D